# numeric constant/forgot concatenate in r

Tags: r, dplyr, concatenation, numeric

I forgot to concatenate the finalgrade column and now cannot erase the `NA` column without getting the phrase `Error: unexpected numeric constant in "grades$NA"` in anything I try. I do not want to redo the whole `data.frame` especially if this happens again.

```
grades<-mutate(grades,finalgrade=NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)

grades
  students    class exam1 exam2 exam3 finalexam finalgrade NA
1     Bill Freshman    80    90    90        92         NA NA
2    Jimbo Sophmore    90    75    50        95         NA NA
3     Jeff   Junior    90    90    95        90         NA NA
4      Jim   Senior    75    75    85        80         NA NA
5   Johnny   Junior    90    90    90        95         NA NA
6     Joey   Senior    65    70    90        45         NA NA
```

Comment: Generally better to give people a concrete example to work with (that can be copy-pasted into R to reproduce), like `library(dplyr); mutate(mtcars[1:3, ], gah = 1, NA, NA)`

Comment: @Frank I have used your example in an edit to my answer. Thanks, I should have thought of that myself.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it must be

```
grades <- mutate(grades, finalgrade = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

Or, more simply,

```
grades$finalgrade <- NA
```

and R will create a column of `NA`'s.

As for the removal of a column, in this case the last one, you can try to assign `NULL` to it.

```
grades[ncol(grades)] <- NULL
```

I will use @Frank's example in a comment to the question to illustrate the code above.

```
library(dplyr)

bad <- mutate(mtcars[1:3, ], gah = NA, NA, NA)
bad
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb gah NA
#1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  NA NA
#2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  NA NA
#3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  NA NA
```

So there is a problem column. Now remove it by assign `NULL` to it.

```
bad[ncol(bad)] <- NULL
bad
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb gah
#1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  NA
#2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  NA
#3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  NA
```

It worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr::select`, you can select columns by their name or position. Here you're trying to keep columns 1 to 7, so you can use those positions in `select`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

grades %>%
  select(1:7)
#>   students    class exam1 exam2 exam3 finalexam finalgrade
#> 1     Bill Freshman    80    90    90        92         NA
#> 2    Jimbo Sophmore    90    75    50        95         NA
#> 3     Jeff   Junior    90    90    95        90         NA
#> 4      Jim   Senior    75    75    85        80         NA
#> 5   Johnny   Junior    90    90    90        95         NA
#> 6     Joey   Senior    65    70    90        45         NA
```

More simply and more scalable, you can use `-` in front of a column name or position to choose which columns to *not* include, and you can use `ncol` to get the number of columns in the data frame, thereby choosing to exclude the last column:

```r
grades %>%
  select(-ncol(.))
#>   students    class exam1 exam2 exam3 finalexam finalgrade
#> 1     Bill Freshman    80    90    90        92         NA
#> 2    Jimbo Sophmore    90    75    50        95         NA
#> 3     Jeff   Junior    90    90    95        90         NA
#> 4      Jim   Senior    75    75    85        80         NA
#> 5   Johnny   Junior    90    90    90        95         NA
#> 6     Joey   Senior    65    70    90        45         NA
```

Created on 2018-08-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).